# Can I get the MongoDB Shell for Windows 32-bit?

Tags: windows, mongodb, shell, 32-bit

How do I get MongoDB Shell for Windows 32-bit operating system? I can find the 32-bit download for the server. I can also find the download for the 64-bit Shell. But there is no option for 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB stopped supporting Windows 32-bit versions since version 3.2. But here are the last 32-bit downloads! https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/i386

Comment: I know about those but what about the shell? Or can I just use the windows command prompt? I thought I needed the shell as well

Comment: You can use it from the command prompt or create an environment variable and open it from the windows run command.